# Sql Server 2016 XML Declaration how to add <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> on the top?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have been looking around how to append

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

to my code

I have a code

```
  SELECT
  [@university] = '159',
  (
    SELECT 
ISNULL(t1.applicationId,'') AS "applicationId",
ISNULL(t1.studentId,'') AS "studentId",
ISNULL(t1.globalId,'') AS "globalId",
ISNULL(t1.LastName,'') AS "LastName",
ISNULL(t1.FirstName,'') AS "FirstName",
ISNULL(t1.preferredFirstName,'') AS "preferredFirstName",
ISNULL(t1.middleName,'') AS "middleName",
ISNULL(t1.suffix,'') AS "suffix",
ISNULL(t1.maidenName,'') AS "maidenName",
ISNULL(t1.addressLine1,'') AS "addressLine1",
ISNULL(t1.addressLine2,'') AS "addressLine2",
ISNULL(t1.addressLine3,'') AS "addressLine3",
ISNULL(t1.city,'') AS "city",
ISNULL(t1.state,'') AS "state",
ISNULL(t1.postalCode,'') AS "postalCode",
ISNULL(t1.countryCode,'') AS "countryCode",
ISNULL(t1.homePhone,'') AS "homePhone",
ISNULL(t1.workPhone,'') AS "workPhone",
ISNULL(t1.cellPhone,'') AS "cellPhone",
ISNULL(t1.email1,'') AS "email1",
ISNULL(t1.email2,'') AS "email2",
ISNULL(t1.institutionEmail,'') AS "institutionEmail",
ISNULL(t1.primaryCitizenship,'') AS "primaryCitizenship",
ISNULL(t1.employer,'') AS "employer",
ISNULL(t1.partnershipCode,'') AS "partnershipCode",
ISNULL(t1.originalExpectedStartDate,'') AS "originalExpectedStartDate",
ISNULL(t1.currentExpectedStartDate,'') AS "currentExpectedStartDate",
ISNULL(t1.actualStartDate,'') AS "actualStartDate",
ISNULL(t1.firstEnrollmentDate,'') AS "firstEnrollmentDate",
ISNULL(t1.applicationStatusCode,'') AS "applicationStatusCode",
ISNULL(t1.applicationStatusDesc,'') AS "applicationStatusDesc",
ISNULL(t1.statusReasonCode,'') AS "statusReasonCode",
ISNULL(statusReasonDesc,'') AS "statusReasonDesc",
ISNULL(t1.appliedDate,'') AS "appliedDate",
ISNULL(t1.applicationFeeStatus,'') AS "applicationFeeStatus",
ISNULL(t1.applicationFeePaidDate,'') AS "applicationFeePaidDate",
ISNULL(t1.applicationPackEvalStatus,'') AS "applicationPackEvalStatus",
ISNULL(t1.applicationPackEvalDate,'') AS "applicationPackEvalDate",
ISNULL(t1.institutionAdmittedDate,'') AS "institutionAdmittedDate",
ISNULL(t1.termAdmitted,'') AS "termAdmitted",
ISNULL(t1.programAdmittedDate,'') AS "programAdmittedDate",
ISNULL(t1.programName,'') AS "programName",
ISNULL(t1.programCode,'') AS "programCode",
ISNULL(t1.programReviewStatusCode,'') AS "programReviewStatusCode",
ISNULL(t1.programReviewStatusDesc,'') AS "programReviewStatusDesc",
ISNULL(t1.programEligibilityStatusCode,'') AS "programEligibilityStatusCode",
ISNULL(t1.programEligibilityStatusDesc,'') AS "programEligibilityStatusDesc",
ISNULL(t1.termEnrolled,'') AS "termEnrolled",
ISNULL(t1.termActivated,'') AS "termActivated",
ISNULL(t1.transferCreditApplied,'') AS "transferCreditApplied",
ISNULL(t1.transferGPA,'') AS "transferGPA",
(
select
ISNULL(t2.holdTypeCode,'') AS "holdTypeCode",
ISNULL(t2.holdTypeDesc,'') AS "holdTypeDesc",
ISNULL(t2.holdDate,'') AS "holdDate",
ISNULL(t2.holdStatusCode,'') AS "holdStatusCode",
ISNULL(t2.holdStatusDesc,'') AS "holdStatusDesc"
from [SAS_IRDM].[dbo].[AP_GRADUATE] as t2
where t2.applicationId=t1.applicationId
FOR XML PATH('hold'),TYPE
)
AS enrollmentHolds
    FROM [AP_GRADUATE] as t1 
    FOR XML PATH('applicant'), TYPE
  )
FOR XML PATH('applicants');
```

but I noticed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

is missing

so I changed to

```
SELECT CONVERT(XML, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'),
  (
  SELECT
  [@university] = '159',
  (
    SELECT 
ISNULL(t1.applicationId,'') AS "applicationId",
ISNULL(t1.studentId,'') AS "studentId",
ISNULL(t1.globalId,'') AS "globalId",
ISNULL(t1.LastName,'') AS "LastName",
ISNULL(t1.FirstName,'') AS "FirstName",
ISNULL(t1.preferredFirstName,'') AS "preferredFirstName",
ISNULL(t1.middleName,'') AS "middleName",
ISNULL(t1.suffix,'') AS "suffix",
ISNULL(t1.maidenName,'') AS "maidenName",
ISNULL(t1.addressLine1,'') AS "addressLine1",
ISNULL(t1.addressLine2,'') AS "addressLine2",
ISNULL(t1.addressLine3,'') AS "addressLine3",
ISNULL(t1.city,'') AS "city",
ISNULL(t1.state,'') AS "state",
ISNULL(t1.postalCode,'') AS "postalCode",
ISNULL(t1.countryCode,'') AS "countryCode",
ISNULL(t1.homePhone,'') AS "homePhone",
ISNULL(t1.workPhone,'') AS "workPhone",
ISNULL(t1.cellPhone,'') AS "cellPhone",
ISNULL(t1.email1,'') AS "email1",
ISNULL(t1.email2,'') AS "email2",
ISNULL(t1.institutionEmail,'') AS "institutionEmail",
ISNULL(t1.primaryCitizenship,'') AS "primaryCitizenship",
ISNULL(t1.employer,'') AS "employer",
ISNULL(t1.partnershipCode,'') AS "partnershipCode",
ISNULL(t1.originalExpectedStartDate,'') AS "originalExpectedStartDate",
ISNULL(t1.currentExpectedStartDate,'') AS "currentExpectedStartDate",
ISNULL(t1.actualStartDate,'') AS "actualStartDate",
ISNULL(t1.firstEnrollmentDate,'') AS "firstEnrollmentDate",
ISNULL(t1.applicationStatusCode,'') AS "applicationStatusCode",
ISNULL(t1.applicationStatusDesc,'') AS "applicationStatusDesc",
ISNULL(t1.statusReasonCode,'') AS "statusReasonCode",
ISNULL(statusReasonDesc,'') AS "statusReasonDesc",
ISNULL(t1.appliedDate,'') AS "appliedDate",
ISNULL(t1.applicationFeeStatus,'') AS "applicationFeeStatus",
ISNULL(t1.applicationFeePaidDate,'') AS "applicationFeePaidDate",
ISNULL(t1.applicationPackEvalStatus,'') AS "applicationPackEvalStatus",
ISNULL(t1.applicationPackEvalDate,'') AS "applicationPackEvalDate",
ISNULL(t1.institutionAdmittedDate,'') AS "institutionAdmittedDate",
ISNULL(t1.termAdmitted,'') AS "termAdmitted",
ISNULL(t1.programAdmittedDate,'') AS "programAdmittedDate",
ISNULL(t1.programName,'') AS "programName",
ISNULL(t1.programCode,'') AS "programCode",
ISNULL(t1.programReviewStatusCode,'') AS "programReviewStatusCode",
ISNULL(t1.programReviewStatusDesc,'') AS "programReviewStatusDesc",
ISNULL(t1.programEligibilityStatusCode,'') AS "programEligibilityStatusCode",
ISNULL(t1.programEligibilityStatusDesc,'') AS "programEligibilityStatusDesc",
ISNULL(t1.termEnrolled,'') AS "termEnrolled",
ISNULL(t1.termActivated,'') AS "termActivated",
ISNULL(t1.transferCreditApplied,'') AS "transferCreditApplied",
ISNULL(t1.transferGPA,'') AS "transferGPA",
(
select
ISNULL(t2.holdTypeCode,'') AS "holdTypeCode",
ISNULL(t2.holdTypeDesc,'') AS "holdTypeDesc",
ISNULL(t2.holdDate,'') AS "holdDate",
ISNULL(t2.holdStatusCode,'') AS "holdStatusCode",
ISNULL(t2.holdStatusDesc,'') AS "holdStatusDesc"
from [SAS_IRDM].[dbo].[AP_GRADUATE] as t2
where t2.applicationId=t1.applicationId
FOR XML PATH('hold'),TYPE
)
AS enrollmentHolds
    FROM [AP_GRADUATE] as t1 
    FOR XML PATH('applicant'), TYPE
  )
FOR XML PATH('applicants')
)
FOR XML PATH('')
```

but the result is

```
&lt;applicants university="159"&gt;&lt;applicant&gt;&lt;applicationId&gt;
```

It is not working,

so how can I add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` the declaration on the top?

Thanks

Comment: On 2016? You won't be able to, it has no built-in support for UTF-8.

Comment: SQL Server's **XML data type** doesn't use XML prolog declaration. XML data type is automatically encoded in UNICODE. It is responsibility of some other layer responsible for serialization to add XML prolog declaration, if needed.

Comment: You can cast the string to varchar and prepend your xnl declaration

Comment: Seems dubious to prepend something saying that it is UTF8 encoded when it is not in fact UTF8 encoded

Answer (score 0):

I could do it Thank you so much for @siggemannen

```
:XML ON

SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + CAST((
  SELECT
  [@university] = '159',
  (
    SELECT 
ISNULL(t1.applicationId,'') AS "applicationId",
ISNULL(t1.studentId,'') AS "studentId",
ISNULL(t1.globalId,'') AS "globalId",
ISNULL(t1.LastName,'') AS "LastName",
ISNULL(t1.FirstName,'') AS "FirstName",
ISNULL(t1.preferredFirstName,'') AS "preferredFirstName",
ISNULL(t1.middleName,'') AS "middleName",
ISNULL(t1.suffix,'') AS "suffix",
ISNULL(t1.maidenName,'') AS "maidenName",
ISNULL(t1.addressLine1,'') AS "addressLine1",
ISNULL(t1.addressLine2,'') AS "addressLine2",
ISNULL(t1.addressLine3,'') AS "addressLine3",
ISNULL(t1.city,'') AS "city",
ISNULL(t1.state,'') AS "state",
ISNULL(t1.postalCode,'') AS "postalCode",
ISNULL(t1.countryCode,'') AS "countryCode",
ISNULL(t1.homePhone,'') AS "homePhone",
ISNULL(t1.workPhone,'') AS "workPhone",
ISNULL(t1.cellPhone,'') AS "cellPhone",
ISNULL(t1.email1,'') AS "email1",
ISNULL(t1.email2,'') AS "email2",
ISNULL(t1.institutionEmail,'') AS "institutionEmail",
ISNULL(t1.primaryCitizenship,'') AS "primaryCitizenship",
ISNULL(t1.employer,'') AS "employer",
ISNULL(t1.partnershipCode,'') AS "partnershipCode",
ISNULL(t1.originalExpectedStartDate,'') AS "originalExpectedStartDate",
ISNULL(t1.currentExpectedStartDate,'') AS "currentExpectedStartDate",
ISNULL(t1.actualStartDate,'') AS "actualStartDate",
ISNULL(t1.firstEnrollmentDate,'') AS "firstEnrollmentDate",
ISNULL(t1.applicationStatusCode,'') AS "applicationStatusCode",
ISNULL(t1.applicationStatusDesc,'') AS "applicationStatusDesc",
ISNULL(t1.statusReasonCode,'') AS "statusReasonCode",
ISNULL(statusReasonDesc,'') AS "statusReasonDesc",
ISNULL(t1.appliedDate,'') AS "appliedDate",
ISNULL(t1.applicationFeeStatus,'') AS "applicationFeeStatus",
ISNULL(t1.applicationFeePaidDate,'') AS "applicationFeePaidDate",
ISNULL(t1.applicationPackEvalStatus,'') AS "applicationPackEvalStatus",
ISNULL(t1.applicationPackEvalDate,'') AS "applicationPackEvalDate",
ISNULL(t1.institutionAdmittedDate,'') AS "institutionAdmittedDate",
ISNULL(t1.termAdmitted,'') AS "termAdmitted",
ISNULL(t1.programAdmittedDate,'') AS "programAdmittedDate",
ISNULL(t1.programName,'') AS "programName",
ISNULL(t1.programCode,'') AS "programCode",
ISNULL(t1.programReviewStatusCode,'') AS "programReviewStatusCode",
ISNULL(t1.programReviewStatusDesc,'') AS "programReviewStatusDesc",
ISNULL(t1.programEligibilityStatusCode,'') AS "programEligibilityStatusCode",
ISNULL(t1.programEligibilityStatusDesc,'') AS "programEligibilityStatusDesc",
ISNULL(t1.termEnrolled,'') AS "termEnrolled",
ISNULL(t1.termActivated,'') AS "termActivated",
ISNULL(t1.transferCreditApplied,'') AS "transferCreditApplied",
ISNULL(t1.transferGPA,'') AS "transferGPA",
(
select
ISNULL(t2.holdTypeCode,'') AS "holdTypeCode",
ISNULL(t2.holdTypeDesc,'') AS "holdTypeDesc",
ISNULL(t2.holdDate,'') AS "holdDate",
ISNULL(t2.holdStatusCode,'') AS "holdStatusCode",
ISNULL(t2.holdStatusDesc,'') AS "holdStatusDesc"
from [AP_GRADUATE] as t2
where t2.applicationId=t1.applicationId
FOR XML PATH('hold'),TYPE
)
AS enrollmentHolds
    FROM [AP_GRADUATE] as t1 
    FOR XML PATH('applicant'), TYPE
  )
FOR XML PATH('applicants')
) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS XmlData
```